# Jenkins master/slave node

Tags: jenkins

I'm configuring Jenkins with a master/slave node. If I mark offline master node, build doesn't starts with this error from log:

"Executor #-1 for master grabbed hudson.model.queue.WorkUnit@2c5affe4[work=pipeline_prova] from queue but master went off-line before the task's worker thread started. No termination trace available."

My question is: in Jenkins, master node must be online in order to launch builds? With Hudson I remember master node should be deactivated.

My actual configuration have master online with 0 executors and 1 slave node using 8 executors. And in this wat works well.

Thanks

Comment: Jenkins uses single master to schedule jobs.
You can also specify executors at the same node where the master runs, but it may lead to extra node load.
Usually jobs should be executed at slave nodes.

Comment: So master must be online, right?

Comment: yes it must be online.

Comment: Yes Jenkins implies single master and this master should be online (see "Durable Task Plugin", though).
There are some approaches to avoid this bottleneck of having to have running single master.
See e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173214/how-to-setup-jenkins-with-ha or https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-core/latest/traditional-install-guide/high-availability or JenkinsX. But I suppose this is not you case.

Answer (score 1):

For me, you just need to go to Manage Jenkins > Nodes to check the nodes used to execute those jobs. [image]

Almost you can check the abnormal issues in that.